# combine raw video and audio buffer and play using named pipes by ffplay

Tags: ffmpeg, named-pipes

I have one video buffer and one audio buffer, I want to combine these buffers and play using ffplay as a combined entity, currently I am using this command , which obliviously doesn't work...

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 1280x720 -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" -i \.\pipe\VirtualVideoPipe -f s32le -channels 2 -sample_rate 44100 -i \.\pipe\VirtualAudioPipe
```

error massage says ...

```
Argument '\.\pipe\VirtualAudioPipe' provided as input filename, but '\.\pipe\VirtualVideoPipe' was already specified.
```

what should be the command for combining two named pipe video and audio sources and play as one.

kindly help ...

Comment: kindly keep in mind that i am very beginner in ffmpeg ffplay... i don't even know some of basic commands, try to help ...

Comment: btw how can i provide two pipes as input to ffplay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 1280x720 -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2" -i \\.\pipe\VirtualVideoPipe | ffplay -f s32le -channels 1 -sample_rate 44100 -i \\.\pipe\VirtualAudioPipe
```

with this command i am able to play streams but they opens in different windows ...

this isn't my answer ...

i want to combine them into a singe window ...